# Inconsistency with add_months function in Hive?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hql

I've lurked on SO for a while but finally have my own question that I could not find on here or on google. Apologies for my inexperience, only a few years out of school. Using Hive 1.2, I've encountered a situation where it appears as though the add_months function is not working properly/consistently.

Simplifying, I essentially have a table with clientid, yyyy-MM, and int.

```
select clientid, concat(yearmonth, '-01'), integer, add_months(concat(yearmonth, '-01'), integer) 
from tablea
where yearmonth = '2015-04' group by clientid, yearmonth, integer;
```

I'm using a where statement because this seems to ONLY affect April and November dates. What happens is that I find:

```
ClientID1, 2015-04-01, 1, 2015-05-01  
ClientID2, 2015-04-01, 1, 2015-05-01  
ClientID3, 2015-04-01, 1, 2015-05-01  
ClientID4, 2015-04-01, 1, 2014-04-30  
ClientID5, 2015-04-01, 1, 2014-04-30  
ClientID6, 2015-04-01, 1, 2014-04-30
```

How does add_months work exactly? (apache link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions). Also if I include another where statement where the add_months result = '2014-04-30', I get returned rows where it actually shows '2015-05-01'. What in the flying heck is going on?

If I change the query superficially (simplify it or make it more complex but have it do basically the same thing) sometimes the results change. Can anyone try and replicate this and let me know I'm not just crazy? Is there any rounding of sorts or anything on my end that could be screwing it up?

Comment: Try `SELECT clientid, concat(yearmonth, '-01'), integer, add_months(CAST(concat(yearmonth, '-01') AS DATE), integer)
FROM tablea
WHERE yearmonth = '2015-04'
GROUP BY clientid, yearmonth, integer;`

Comment: @MRSrinivas I was actually thinking of doing that. Though I'm puzzled as why it should matter as the documentation states it takes date/string/timestamp as a parameter? Will try now though.

Comment: @MRSrinivas No luck; it seems to have addressed November but not April. I'm still confused as to how or why this would only be affecting certain months...

Answer (score 0):

While working with dates use feilds in DATE format so engine will take care other things like leap year or days in month etc. (adding / substracting )

### Make sure your field does not have blanks or especial chars, I have following and it works perfectly

File 
    ClientID1, 2015-01,1
    ClientID2, 2015-02,1
    ClientID3, 2015-04,1
    ClientID4, 2015-04,1
    ClientID5, 2015-05,1
    ClientID6, 2015-06,1
    ClientID7, 2015-07,1
    ClientID8, 2015-08,1
    ClientID9, 2015-09,1
    ClientID10, 2015-10,1
    ClientID11, 2015-11,1
    ClientID12, 2015-12,1

```
Create table date_nov (client String, datemonth String, x int )  ROW FORMAT     DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/root/date_nov.txt' into TABLE date_nov ;

hive> select * from date_nov;
OK
ClientID1        2015-01        1
ClientID2        2015-02        1
ClientID3        2015-04        1
ClientID4        2015-04        1
ClientID5        2015-05        1
ClientID6        2015-06        1
ClientID7        2015-07        1
ClientID8        2015-08        1
ClientID9        2015-09        1
ClientID10       2015-10        1
ClientID11       2015-11        1
ClientID12       2015-12        1

select * , add_months(to_DATE(concat(trim(datemonth),'-01' )),x)   from date_nov;

---------------------------------------
```

Comment: But the documentation on add_months states that it takes date/string/timestamp as parameters? Also I have tried casting to date--it seems to only have fixed November dates. Something fishy is going on...

Comment: I have edited withnew SQL, Let me know if thats works

Comment: So 99% of the time, add_months works as intended. Doing any simple test to attempt to replicate the bug does not show any issues (as you have tested). I seem to have found a situation where it is not working properly--recently confirmed the bug with a senior data architect. Still not sure what triggers it, but will report the bug once we have more time to sit down and figure out a simple replication. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: ok, send me the data when you encounter the special data issue.